# My Index.php is opening as a javascript, no code is visible

Tags: javascript, html

Please consider that I've done my research, I'm clearly here because I cannot figure out what's wrong.

I'm trying to open my index.html file, using Dreamweaver, the file size is 41KB, once I open it I get this:

[image]

I have 1 year worth of experience learning html and such, so please don't think that I'm trying to get an answer and just run, I haven't come across this problem before.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Post the actual source code.

Comment: You have to show a bit more of your file... did you actually write that long string?

Comment: @Blender I can't, this is the actual source code when I open my index.

Comment: Open the file with a "vanilla" text editor. What was the source of the file - did you create it in Dreamweaver?

Comment: @Floris , this is all I am getting to show

Comment: @Floris , yes the file was created in Dreamweaver, the source was created using Dreamweaver too and was working, I am unsure what caused it to turn into a Javascript

Comment: @user2495378: That's what I'm talking about. Paste the beginning (i.e. a large chunk) of the file here.

Comment: Open it in Chrome and inspect the DOM with the developer tools. What do you see?

Comment: Clearly there appears to be no <html> tag at the beginning of your file... could it be that simple?

Comment: That doesn't look like something Dreamweaver would do on it's own. That code appears to have been deliberately obfuscated.

Comment: @Dracs is right - this looks like it could have the makings of a nasty worm, actually.

Comment: Could it be possibly this would happen after zipping the file? @Dracs

Comment: Anything I adjust on the page will render the page unusable...

Comment: @user2495378 No, that code could very well render a HTML page (although it violates a few standards). If you post the actual (text) code for us we could de-obfuscate it for you. Obfuscation like this is generally done to prevent others from using their code or to make it harder to determine the purpose of malware.

Comment: Ah - That's what I'm trying to figure out, there is no actual text code visible anywhere!

Comment: I manually decoded just the first few characters: it comes out as `<!doctype html`...

Comment: @user2495378: Not a wise assumption. Paste the source here and it'll be easy to tell. Nobody's going to OCR the screenshot.

Comment: It is possible to "decode" this entire file; then you can see if it is infected or not.

Comment: @user2495378 That 'gibberish' is the HTML text code. If you post the text we can covert it to regular HTML code.

Comment: @Blender Here it is: http://htmlpaste.com/65a085418300378f32e25e74d24088aaea4e9ded

Comment: @user2495378: Nope, that's legit HTML. I've never seen anything like this happen.

Comment: Which is why it has left me very baffled @Blender

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the source code of a webpage that has been through this **source code encrypter**.

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/encrypter.htm

Are you trying to copy someone else's code? If the page creator 'encrypted' their source, it can still be viewed live (in Chrome, right click Inspect Element).

**EDIT:**

**Here's your code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Abbey Boilers - Your first choice Boiler company</title>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="js/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="css/style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="css/media_queries.css"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

<!-- JS -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>

<!--  <script src="js/less-grid-4.js"></script> -->
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="js/tabs.js"></script>

<!-- Masonry -->
<script src="js/masonry.min.js" ></script>
<script src="js/imagesloaded.js" ></script>
<!-- ENDS Masonry -->

<!-- Tweet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.tweet.css" media="all"  />
<script src="js/tweet/jquery.tweet.js" ></script>
<!-- ENDS Tweet -->

<!-- superfish -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/superfish.css" />
<script  src="js/superfish-1.4.8/js/hoverIntent.js"></script>
<script  src="js/superfish-1.4.8/js/superfish.js"></script>
<script  src="js/superfish-1.4.8/js/supersubs.js"></script>
<!-- ENDS superfish -->

<!-- prettyPhoto -->
<script  src="js/prettyPhoto/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/prettyPhoto/css/prettyPhoto.css"  media="screen" />
<!-- ENDS prettyPhoto -->

<!-- poshytip -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/poshytip-1.1/src/tip-twitter/tip-twitter.css"  />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/poshytip-1.1/src/tip-yellowsimple/tip-yellowsimple.css"  />
<script  src="js/poshytip-1.1/src/jquery.poshytip.min.js"></script>
<!-- ENDS poshytip -->

<!-- GOOGLE FONTS -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allan:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- Flex Slider -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css" >
<script src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<!-- ENDS Flex Slider -->

<!--[if IE 6]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie6-hacks.css" media="screen" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/DD_belatedPNG.js"></script>
            <script>
                /* EXAMPLE */
                DD_belatedPNG.fix('*');
            </script>
        <![endif]-->

<!-- Lessgrid -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="css/lessgrid.css"/>

<!-- modernizr -->
<script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr.custom.17475.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/elastislide.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css" />

</head>

<body lang="en">

<!-- mobile-nav -->
<div id="mobile-nav-holder">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul id="mobile-nav">
      <li  class="current-menu-item"><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about_us.html">About us</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Features</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Features</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Features</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Features</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="servicing.html">Servicing</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="nav-open"><a href="#">Menu</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ENDS mobile-nav -->

<header>
  <div class="wrapper"> <a href="index.html" id="logo"><img src="img/LogoForWebsite.png" alt="Tandem"></a>
    <nav>
      <ul id="nav" class="sf-menu">
        <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="index.html">Home<span class="subheader">welcome</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="about_us.html">About us<span class="subheader">Get in touch</span></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Find us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="servicing.html">Servicing<span class="subheader">Boiler Installations</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact us<span class="subheader">get in touch</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="contact_detials"><img src="img/ContactDetails.png"></div>
<!-- MAIN -->
<div id="main"> 

  <!-- social -->
  <div id="social-bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com"  title="Become a fan"><img src="img/social/facebook_32.png"  alt="Facebook" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com" title="Follow my tweets"><img src="img/social/twitter_32.png"  alt="Facebook" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.google.com"  title="Add to the circle"><img src="img/social/google_plus_32.png" alt="Facebook" /></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- ENDS social --> 

  <!-- Content -->
  <div id="content">

  <!-- slider -->
  <div class="flexslider home-slider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li> <img src="img/slides/slide1.jpg" alt="alt text" />
        <p class="flex-caption"><em>Highest Quality Service Gauranteed, Our priority is you.</em> </p>
      </li>
      <li> <img src="img/slides/slide2.jpg" alt="alt text" />
        <p class="flex-caption"><em>Highest Quality Service Gauranteed, Our priority is you.</em></p>
      </li>
      <li> <img src="img/slides/slide3.jpg" alt="alt text" />
        <p class="flex-caption"><em>Highest Quality Service Gauranteed, Our priority is you.</em></p>
      </li>
      <li> <img src="img/slides/slide4.jpg" alt="alt text" />
        <p class="flex-caption"><em>Highest Quality Service Gauranteed, Our priority is you.</em></p>
      </li>
      <li> <img src="img/slides/slide5.jpg" alt="alt text" />
        <p class="flex-caption"><em>Highest Quality Service Gauranteed, Our priority is you.</em></p>
      </li>
      <li> <img src="img/slides/slide6.jpg" alt="alt text" />
        <p class="flex-caption"><em>Highest Quality Service Gauranteed, Our priority is you.</em></p>
      </li>
      <li> <img src="img/slides/slide7.jpg" alt="alt text" />
        <p class="flex-caption"><em>Highest Quality Service Gauranteed, Our priority is you.</em></p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="shadow-slider"></div>
  <!-- ENDS slider --> 

  <!-- Headline -->
  <div class="headline">
    <p>"We are a domestic boiler company who deal with servicing, repair and installation with a wide range of experience in gas, oil and LPG appliances. Our uniformed service engineers are trained to both GAS SAFE and OFTEC Standards, with ongoing training alongside well known boiler manufacturers to ensure we do not become complacent.
      Our training covers all types of appliances, including, the standard boiler, combination boilers, condensing boilers and warm air units - all the way to gas fires and range cookers. Including engineering who specialist in Aga, Rayburn and Alpha Range Cookers.</p>
    <p>We aim to give you a service with a difference, our priority is customer satisfaction as we are aware that customers have the choice and want to make sure your experience with Abbey Boilers is one you'll come back to. We can cover a wide range of problems you might encounter, from the initial call to our customer services - to the engineering attending your home right through to our accounts manager making sure everything is run pleasantly and smoothly" </p>
  </div>

  <!-- ENDS Headline --> 

  <!-- featured -->
  <h1 class="home-block-heading">Our Services</h1>
  <div class="featured">
    <figure> <a href="images/UnderFloor Heating Example.jpg" data-rel="prettyPhoto" class="thumb"><img src="images/UnderFloor Heating Example.jpg" alt="Underfloor Heating" /></a>
      <div> <a href="#" class="heading">
        <h3>Maximises the efficiency of condensing boilers and heat pumps due to lower working temperatures - Eliminates the need for radiators: creates space on walls and allows unrestricted room layouts
          Cleaner air for the home - radiant heat results in less circulation of dust than with radiators
          Complete heating and hot water solutions from one manufacturer -complements Worcester gas boilers, oil boilers, ground and air source heat pumps</h3>
      </div>
      <a class="link" href="#"></a> </figure>
    <figure style="left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;"> <a href="img/dummies/full-2.jpg" data-rel="prettyPhoto" class="thumb"><img src="img/dummies/full-2.jpg" alt="Alt text" /></a>
      <div> <a href="#" class="heading">Pellentesque habitant</a> morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. </div>
      <a class="link" href="#"></a> </figure>
    <figure style="left: 310px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;"> <a href="img/dummies/full-3.jpg" data-rel="prettyPhoto" class="thumb"><img src="img/dummies/full-3.jpg" alt="Alt text" /></a>
      <div> <a href="#" class="heading">Pellentesque habitant</a> morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas address. Vestibulum tortor quam, </div>
      <a class="link" href="#"></a> </figure>
    <figure> <a href="img/dummies/full-4.jpg" data-rel="prettyPhoto" class="thumb"><img src="img/dummies/full-4.jpg" alt="Alt text" /></a>
      <div> <a href="#" class="heading">Pellentesque habitant</a> morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas address. Vestibulum tortorVestibulum tortor.</div>
      <a class="link" href="#"></a> </figure>
    <figure> <a href="img/dummies/full-5.jpg" data-rel="prettyPhoto" class="thumb"><img src="img/dummies/full-5.jpg" alt="Alt text" /></a>
      <div> <a href="#" class="heading">Pellentesque habitant</a> morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas address. Vestibulum </div>
      <a class="link" href="#"></a> </figure>
    <figure> <a href="img/dummies/full-6.jpg" data-rel="prettyPhoto" class="thumb"><img src="img/dummies/full-6.jpg" alt="Alt text" /></a>
      <div> <a href="#" class="heading">Pellentesque habitant</a> morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas address. Vestibulum<a href="#" >Pellentesque habitant</a>. </div>
      <a class="link" href="#"></a> </figure>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- ENDS featured --> 

  <!-- Elastislide Carousel -->
  <div style="margin-bottom:30px;">
    <ul id="carousel" class="elastislide-list">
        <li><a href="#1"><img src="images/small/1.png" alt="image01" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#2"><img src="images/small/2.png" alt="image02" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#3"><img src="images/small/3.png" alt="image03" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#4"><img src="images/small/4.png" alt="image04" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#5"><img src="images/small/5.png" alt="image05" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#6"><img src="images/small/6.png" alt="image06" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#7"><img src="images/small/7.png" alt="image07" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#8"><img src="images/small/8.png" alt="image08" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#9"><img src="images/small/9.png" alt="image09" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#10"><img src="images/small/10.png" alt="image10" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#11"><img src="images/small/11.png" alt="image11" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#12"><img src="images/small/12.png" alt="image12" /></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div></div>

  <!-- End Elastislide Carousel -->

  <!-- text-posts -->
  <h1 class="home-block-heading">Allow us to introduce Abbey Boilers...</h1>
  <ul class="text-posts">
    <li>
      <h5 align="center" style="font-family: 'Dosis';"> We are a domestic  boiler company who deal with servicing, repair and installation with a wide  range of experience in gas, oil and LPG appliances. Our uniformed service  engineers are trained to both GAS SAFE and OFTEC Standards, with ongoing training  alongside well known boiler manufacturers to ensure we do not become  complacent.  <br>
        <br>
        Our training  covers all types of appliances, including, the standard boiler, combination  boilers, condensing boilers and warm air units - all the way to gas fires and  range cookers. Including engineering who specialist in Aga, Rayburn and Alpha  Range Cookers.<br>
        <br>
        We aim to give you a  service with a difference, our priority is customer satisfaction as we are  aware that customers have the choice and want to make sure your experience with  Abbey Boilers is one you'll come back to. We can cover a wide range of problems  you might encounter, from the initial call to our customer services - to the  engineering attending your home right through to our accounts manager making  sure everything is run pleasantly and smoothly</h5>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- ENDS text-posts -->

  <!-- Footline -->
  <div class="headline" style="margin-bottom:0;">
    <p style="text-align:center;">"Abbey Boilers is a Division of Greener Energy Ltd.<br />
    Abbey House, Unit 24, Foundry Lane, Horsham, West Sussex. RH13 5UE<br />
    Registered in England & Wales No. 7559426 - Gas Safe No 529002<br />
    Vat No. 111 6410 69"</p>
  </div>
  <!-- ENDS Footline --> 

</div>
<!-- ENDS content -->

<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="shadow-main"></div>
</div>
<!-- ENDS MAIN -->

<!--Some JavaScripts-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquerypp.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.elastislide.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $( '#carousel' ).elastislide();

</script>

<!--End JavaScripts-->

<footer>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="gas_logo"><img src="img/gasSafe.png"></div>
    <ul id="footer-cols">
      <li class="second-col" style="margin-top:10px;">
        <p>Copyright &copy; Abbey Boilers</p>
      </li>
      <li class="third-col">
        <div class="widget-block"> 
          <!--<div id="tweets" class="footer-col tweet">
            <h4>Contact us</h4>
          </div>--> 
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="to-top"></div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>'));
</Script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @redditor I had given my code to someone to make a couple adjustments for me but I'm the original source code creator, so what's the best thing for me to do at this point?

Comment: @user2495378 The link I included in my answer also includes a button called 'Source'. Paste your code in the box and hit that button. In most cases, all you would need to do then is delete the first and last three lines and you have a full functional code. Please mark my answer as correct and upvote if you haven't already - Thanks.

Comment: @user2495378 I have added the code in my answer as per your link in another commment.